# ¿Como modificar valores de una lista en python y agregarlos a otra?

Tags: python, lista

tengo esta lista: **wrds = ["end", 'work', "play", "start", "walk", "look", "open", "rain", "learn", "clean"]** ¿Como puedo agregar "ed" al final de cada uno de los elementos y guardarla en otra lista diferente?

Comment: `wrds_ed = [f"{word}ed" for word in wrds]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Para iterar una lista en python tienes varias opciones, puedes utilizar un `for` un `while` o utilizar `list comprehension`. [Aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_loop.asp) hay una página que explica los diferentes métodos para iterar (Recorrer) los elementos dentro de una lista.

Puedes resolverlo de la siguiente forma:

### Opción 1

Con un ciclo `for`

```
wrds = ["end", 'work', "play", "start", "walk", "look", "open", "rain", "learn", "clean"]

nuevaListaFor = []

for word in wrds:
  nuevaListaFor.append(word + 'ed')

print(nuevaListaFor)
```

### Opción 2

Con un ciclo `while`

```
wrds = ["end", 'work', "play", "start", "walk", "look", "open", "rain", "learn", "clean"]

nuevaListaWhile = []
i = 0
while i < len(wrds):
  nuevaListaWhile.append(wrds[i] + 'ed')
  i = i + 1

print(nuevaListaWhile)
```

### Opción 3

Con `list comprehension` (Tal como mencionó @Christian en el comentario a tu pregunta)

```
wrds = ["end", 'work', "play", "start", "walk", "look", "open", "rain", "learn", "clean"]

nuevaListaListComprehension = [f"{word}ed" for word in wrds]
  
print(nuevaListaListComprehension)
```